# Make NA observations that are identical with observations in adjacent column

Tags: r

My data frame:

```
     structure(list(make = c("land rover", "land rover", "land rover", 
    "land rover", "land rover", "land rover", "land rover", "land rover", 
    "land rover", "land rover"), model = c("freelander", "range", 
    "discovery", "freelander", "range", "discovery", "discovery", 
    "range", "discovery", "range"), body = c("freelander", "sport", 
    "discovery", "2", "evoque", "sport", "4x4", "range", "4", "sport"
    )), .Names = c("make", "model", "body"), row.names = c(92L, 178L, 
    185L, 192L, 202L, 224L, 233L, 448L, 473L, 480L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to NA those observations in column 'body' that are identical to observations in column 'model'. In this case this would be rows 1,3,8.
I tried the following function which does not give any errors, but also does not produce any results:

```
RemovingNames <- function(df){
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) 
  ifelse(identical (df[i,2], df[i,3]), df[i,3]<-NA, df[i,3]<-df[i,3])
 }
```

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop `df1[,3][df1[,2]==df1[,3]] <- NA`

Comment: Thanks I was overcomplicating. Would accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your dataset "test", then:

```
test[test[,"model"] == test[, "body"], "body"] <- NA
```